# Linking three drop down menu together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to recreate a "linked" drop down menu by using someone else's code but extend it to link not just 2 but 3. Now my code is working but I am facing 2 problems all to do with the final link!

1. the final "3rd" drop down (organiser) displays the same organisers doesn't matter which "state" and/or "store" were chosen
2. the final "3rd" drop down (organiser) doesn't reset to "select the organiser" when new "State" and or "store were picked. The second one "store" does when new "state" is picked.

Thank you for your advice!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <style type="text/css">
            .subcat option {
                display: none;
            }
            .subcat option.label {
                display: inline;
            }
        </style>
<script> 
            function goToNewPage()
          {
            var url = document.getElementById('organiser').value;
            console.log(url);
            if(url != 'none') {
              window.location = url;
            }
          }
          </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    
    var $cat = $("#state"),
        $subcat = $(".subcat");
        $organiser = $(".organiser");
    
    $cat.on("change",function(){
        var _rel = $(this).val();
        $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
        $subcat.val("");
        if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
        $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
        $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
    });
    $subcat.on("change",function(){ 
        var _org = $(this).val(); 
        $organiser.find("option").attr("style",""); 
        $organiser.val(""); 
        if(!_org) return $organiser.prop("disabled",true); 
        $organiser.find("[org="+_org+"]").show();
        $organiser.prop("disabled",false); });
            
    });
</script>
<form id="formname" name="Sate-Store">
    
                    <select name="state" id="state">
                        <option value="">Select state</option>
                        <option value="ma">MA</option>
                        <option value="me">ME</option>
                        <option value="nh">NH</option>
                    </select>
                    <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="store" name="store">
                        <option value>Select a store</option>
                        <!-- MA -->
                        <option rel="ma" value="ma_store_1">MA Store 1</option>
            <option rel="ma" value="http://www.google.com">MA Store 2</option>
                        <option rel="ma" value="ma_store_3">MA Store 3</option>
                        <option rel="ma" value="ma_store_4">MA Store 4</option>
                        <option rel="ma" value="ma_store_5">MA Store 5</option>
                        <!-- ME -->
                        <option rel="me" value="me_store_1">ME Store 1</option>
                        <option rel="me" value="me_store_2">ME Store 2</option>
                        <option rel="me" value="me_store_3">ME Store 3</option>
                        <option rel="me" value="me_store_4">ME Store 4</option>
                        <option rel="me" value="me_store_5">ME Store 5</option>
                        <!-- MH -->
                        <option rel="nh" value="nh_store_1">NH Store 1</option>
                        <option rel="nh" value="nh_store_2">NH Store 2</option>
                        <option rel="nh" value="nh_store_3">NH Store 3</option>
                        <option rel="nh" value="nh_store_4">NH Store 4</option>
                        <option rel="nh" value="nh_store_5">NH Store 5</option>
                    </select>
                                        <select disabled="disabled" class="organiser" id="organiser" name="organiser">
                                            <option value>Select the organiser</option>
                                            <!-- MA -->
                                            <option org="ma_store_1" value="https://test.com/">Jack</option>
                                            <option org="ma_store_1" value="James">James</option>
                                            <option org="ma_store_1" value="Frank">Frank</option>
                                        </select>

          <input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()" />

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Tried Jfiddle and the code still have the same problem.

Comment: It sounds like your third <select> is not at all dependent on the first two, is that correct? So it can be static, no need to "link" it.

Comment: It is linked to first two. It won't display options until the first and second drop down are selected. But 2 problems as listed above.

Comment: Just to keep everything equivalent change the 2nd and 3rd dropdowns to an ID reference like the first, $subcat = $("#store"); and $organiser = $("#organiser");  It sounds like the behavior of the 1st and 2nd are working, so model everything on the 1st dropdown.

Comment: That change breaks the whole code, unfortunately.